# p already declared error

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm running following query:

```
START root=node:people(id="$personOrFamilyId"), descendant=node:people(id="$descendant") 
MATCH p=shortestPath(root-[p:child|descendant*..25]->descendant) 
RETURN EXTRACT( n in nodes(p) : n.id ) as node_ids_on_path
```

and get following error:

```
p already declared
```

It was working in 1.9, but in 2.0 it's failing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reusing the identifier `p` for both the path coming out of the shortestPath, as well as the relationship identifier inside of the pattern.

```
START root=node:people(id="$personOrFamilyId"), descendant=node:people(id="$descendant") 
MATCH p=shortestPath(root-[:child|descendant*..25]->descendant) 
RETURN EXTRACT( n in nodes(p) | n.id ) as node_ids_on_path
```

Comment: now I get: extract(...) requires '| expression' (an extract expression)

Comment: ah, indeed. missed that--the extract function now takes a pipe.